# ngDupes error with the checkboxes AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to fix my ngdupes error with the checkbox selection. I don't know what's going wrong. Can someone please help? Here is my code:

```
$scope.GetMultiCheckBox = function GetMultiCheckBox(CheckBoxs) {
    var idx = $scope.selectedfunction.indexOf(CheckBoxs);
    if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selectedfunction.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
        $scope.selectedfunction.push(CheckBoxs);
    }
};
$scope.FilterValueByFunction = function (FunctionVal) {
    $scope.Lv7 = [];
    if (!$scope.selectedfunction.length == '') {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.LoadAllData.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.selectedfunction.length; j++) {
                if ($scope.LoadAllData[i].Business_x0020_Checkbox.results.toString().match($scope.selectedfunction[j])) {
                    $scope.Lv7.push($scope.LoadAllData[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.LoadAllData.length; i++) {
            $scope.Lv7.push($scope.LoadAllData[i]);
        }
    } 
};
```

Here is my HTML code for checkboxes:

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="item in functions">
<input id="{{item}}" type="checkbox" value="{{item}}" ng-disabled="Site.length == 0"    
     ng-checked="selectedFunction.indexOf(item) > -1"
     ng-click="GetMultiCheckBox(item); FilterValueByFunction(item);" autocomplete="off"/></li></ul>
```

This is the code for the whole data getting filtered based on choices:

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in Lv8|orderBy: 'Category'| filter: SiteFilter 
    |groupBy: 'Category' | filter: searchBox">
            <div  id="grad1" ng-show="item.Category_CHANGED">{{item.Category}} 
   </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need to show your full HTML code

Comment: extend your `ng-repeat` queries with `track by $index`, e.g. `ng-repeat="item in functions track by $index"`, this will allow you to use duplicated values